# How can I create a panel layout with grouped plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering if you could help me with something.

I'm currently writing some papers with regression analyses (and scatter plots with fitted lines). I'd like to merge all my plots into a single panel as shown.

I've already stacked some plots using grid.arrange from gridExtra (which go in box A), but I have no clue how to:

- Create boxes A, B, C, (...), each with its own letter on the top-left corner. Each box contains stacked plots (2 or 3 rows depending on the # of models, with all plots for a single model on the same row) linear regression plots.
- Place color labels on top of the boxes (e.g Social Cognition and Moral Judgement)
- Place vertical text (which would serve as the Y label) such as Risk Perception and Impact Estimation

Thank you very much
[This is the referenced layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAXOE.png)

Comment: Do you want to join all the plots in a single view? That's what are you looking for?

Comment: Yes, with all the details from the sample layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot multiple charts within the same chart area. You can do this with the standard graphics functions by setting the `mfcol` parameter for a device. For example, to plot six figures within the plot area in three rows of two columns, you would set `mfcol` as follows:

```
par(mfcol=c(3, 2))
```

Each time a new figure is plotted, it will be plotted in a different row or column within the device, starting with the top-left corner.

So you can use `plot` or `ggplot` or another plotting package and the plot will be added to the layer.